# Functions orthogonal to linear span when considering a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, orthogonality, projection, symmetric-functions

Let $x \sim N(0, 1)$ be a random variable distributed as standard normal.

I am looking for functions that satisfy $$E[x f(x)] = 0 $$.

In particular, functions whose best approximation is a constant when the underlying distribution is standard normal.

I know that for example any $f(x) = a x^p$ with $p$ an even positive integer and $a$ any real number satisfy the restriction. I think that perhaps any symmetric function around zero satisfies the restriction, but I haven't proved it.

Are there any others? Any hints or related literature on how to find them?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you may want to read something about the Hermite polynomials. And, yes, if $f(-t)=f(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$ then $E(xf(x))=0$, because the left-hand side is, up to constants, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty X f(X) e^{-X^2}\, dX, $$ and thechange of variable $X\mapsto -X$ does the trick

Comment: One could reduce the problem to simply $E[g(x)]=0$ using “Gaussian integration by parts”: $E[xF(x)]=E[F'(x)]$ for any “nice” function $F$ (e.g., continuously differentiable with $F(y)=o(\mathrm e^{y^2})$ as $|y|\to\infty$).